# DirectoryNotFoundException in VS Code Azure Functions extension after updating .NET SDK

Tags: azure-functions

After updating .NET SDK to 6.0.200 "Deploy to Function App..." feature of Azure Functions VS Code extension fails with:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.200\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error MSB3883: Unexpected exception:  [C:\git\x\project1\project1.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.200\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error : DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\git\x\project1\bin\Release\net6.0\ref\project1.dll'. [C:\git\x\project1\project1.csproj]
```

The files are in

`C:\git\x\project1\bin\Release\net6.0\` but not in

`C:\git\x\project1\bin\Release\net6.0\ref`

What to do do fix this?

Comment: I raised this at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/3051

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because of this braking change:

[Write reference assemblies to intermediate output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/6.0/write-reference-assemblies-to-obj)

### Workround/solution

Until a new version of the Azure Functions extension is released, I think, the workaround is to follow [Write reference assemblies to intermediate output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/6.0/write-reference-assemblies-to-obj) and set `ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir` in the project file.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>true</ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
```